# socket.io and differents folders --- solution found

Tags: socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and i already have a problem, minor i think. 
I have installed node.js properly and socket.io too with npm. Then just for testing i cut and paste a sample of code from socket.io and everything works well. 
Now, i want to strcuture my code and folders and i have created a folder "client" to put a fresh new js file client.js with the client code from the example. 
Here is my architecture

```
/client
    client.js
index.html 
server.js
```

client.js :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    alert('sqd');
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf-8',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html ' + __dirname);
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i refresh my browser at localhost:80 i have a error on my client.js :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

It seems that there's a problem to interpret my js file as a js file. I've read some threads on the question but nothing works.

Can you help me please ?

Thanx :)

---

Ok i've found a solution... You have to specify the content type for each file request in a static webserver. May be it could help someone.
Here is the handler function :

```
function handler (req, res) {

  var filePath = req.url;

  if (filePath == '/') {
      filePath = './client/index.html';
  } else {
      filePath = './client/lib' + req.url;
  }

  var extname = path.extname(filePath);
  var contentType = 'text/html';

  switch (extname) {
    case '.js':
        contentType = 'text/javascript';
        break;
    case '.css':
        contentType = 'text/css';
        break;
  }

  path.exists(filePath, function(exists) {

    if (exists) {
        fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
            if (error) {
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end();
            }
            else {
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                res.end(content, 'utf-8');
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this can help someone. 
I love to post a problem and respond by myself with no help. Somehow it meens that i'm desesperate too fast. And i love to tell my life in a post too :) 
Ok i'm gonna eat something and drink more coffee !!!

Comment: Thank you for addressing this issue. I have a small problem though: In my case this code returns the following error: path is undefined. Any thoughts on that would be welcome

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much! This solved my problem!! And I changed the switch to following code:

```
var extname = path.extname(filePath);
var contentTypesByExtention = {
  'html': 'text/html',
  'js':   'text/javascript',
  'css':  'text/css'
};
var contentType = contentTypesByExtention[extname] || 'text/plain';
```

It may be easier to maintain :)

Answer (score 2):

Only that solves:

```
function handler (request, response) {
    var file = __dirname + (request.url == '/' ? '/index.html' : request.url);
    fs.readFile(file, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(500);
            return response.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end(data, 'utf-8');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's what i need! thank you! 
and 
we'll add one code line a top of

> server.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')
  **, path = require('path')**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mime` module as well:

```
var mime = require('mime')
  , content_type = mime.lookup(filePath);

// handle the request here ...

response.setHeader('Content-Type', content_type);
response.writeHead(200);
response.end(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

And you must made `fs.readFile` wrapped by a closure, otherwise some file (especially the last file) will be read more than once, and others will not be read at all. And the `contentType`will not be set as you wish. This is because of the callback strategy used by `fs.readFile`. The problem does not appear when the html file just load one external file, but as the external files(css, js, png) loaded more than one it will appear as i pointed out above. (I came upoon this by myself)

So your code should make a little change as follows:

```
;(function (filename, contentType) {

    fs.readFile(filename, function(err, file) {
        // do the left stuff here
    });

}(filename, contentType));
```