# Opencart website with CSS issue

Tags: php, javascript, opencart, cloudflare

Looking at the chrome console I find this warning: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://wisdomsurvival.com/min/mi6wgylumfwg6zzpozuwk5zporugk3lff5zwq33qobuxuyjpon2hs3dfonugkzlu/my6xg5dznrsxg2dfmv2c4y3tom/combined.css"

In the network bar it also appears that combined.css is text/html and not text/css like the other css files

I am not sure if that's why my website doesn't seem to be loading properly or what is causing this.

wisdomsurvival.com

I've only got basic knowledge so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I disabled this feature which fixed the css issue but I noticed the other pages of the site are getting a 404 error. I have opencarts built in SEO url's feature enabled although disabling doesn't fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL has been minified (I think by the Increase page speed modification) and you will need to contact the author of the modification to get it to transfer correctly. This is not a standard feature of any version of OC to date

Answer (score -1):

You need to send valid HTML mime type from server
Refer to answer link below
[Chrome says "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641168/chrome-says-resource-interpreted-as-stylesheet-but-transferred-with-mime-type-t)